# Accessing COM Object from WinRT C++ Component

Tags: c++, uwp, com, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I would like to write a WinRT (C++) component that access my COM Object.
in order to do that I need the COM Object Interface definitions, so I'm using `#import` with     `raw_interfaces_only`

e.g.

```
#import "libid:ee10004c-2d77-4289-bb93-d6def17881dd" raw_interfaces_only
```

the problem is that I'm getting the following error on the autogenerate .tlh file:

```
fatal error C1075: '{': no matching token found
```

The same code works fine in regular windows console application.

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-com) COM Consuming is supported by WinRT, so it is not clear how can I import my Interface to WinRT C++ Project.

**How do I import my COM Interfaces definition to my WinRT C++ Project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using midl.exe (included in Visual Studio) I was able to to generate a .H file that contains all of the definition and compile fine in WinRT component.

```
midle.exe myinterface.idl
```

this Generate header file that can be included in the WinRT Project.